# usps international shipping api not working one magento 1.6

Tags: magento, usps

I've searched forums around the net for hours. It seems there's a bug in the usps api for magento 1.6. We've upgraded our site from magento 1.4 where everything was working fine and now we're stuck with this bug and cannot offer international shipping. We are in production mode, confirmed our credentials with USPS themselves, and no matter what I tried, I keep on getting *"no shipping methods available"* error for shipping outside the US. 
When I tried logging the usps module for errors, I get an error that says something about USERID and looks like this:

```
DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<IntlRateV2Request USERID="
    [result] => <Error>
 <Number>80040b19</Number>
 <Description>XML Syntax Error: Error getting USERID attribute.</Description>
 <Source>UspsCom::DoAuth</Source>
</Error>
    [__pid] => 32693
)
```

I haven't found any documentation on this error and we're near to giving up on this but it simply can't be that this cannot be solved. Did anyone out there encounter a similar problem or better yet, did anyone ever solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade from 1.4 to 1.6 you have to re-enter the account information under configuration->shipping methods in the Magento admin.

The encryption/decryptions routines changed in those versions so account information that is encrypted in 1.4 is decrypted differently in 1.6.